# PHP radio button - undefined index

Tags: php

Simple question, when I didn't select any radio button, I got error message
Undefined index: gender

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    echo $gender;
    }
?>

<html>
    <form action="testing.php" method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['register'])){


    if(!empty($_POST['gender'])) {

        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        echo $gender;

        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <form action="radio.php" method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"  />Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use @$_POST['gender'] to not raise the error

Comment: helpful answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked radio buttons and checkboxes don't get posted by the form, so they won't appear in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you get an error when you don't select a radio button.
Because when you don't select one the value isn't posted.
You can 1) check if the index exist with isset() or 2) make a radio button checked on page load so that the value is always send.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the 'gender' inputs does not get submitted if there is no selected radio button. This is the same as not ticking a checkbox. You need to check if it exists and has a valid value by using

```
if(!empty($_POST['gender'])) {
    ...
}
```

Other ways of checking include `isset($_POST['gender'])` and `array_key_exists('gender', $_POST)` though these do not check if the value is zero or the empty string (which may or may not be what you want)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$_POST['gender']`. Since you didnt select anything, gender is undefined.

You can check for a defined index using `array_key_exists('gender', $_POST)`

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be easily solved this way.

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    if(isset($_POST['gender'])) {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    }else{
        $gender = "";
    }
}
```

If you need to validate with PHP you can do so against the $gender = "";

```
<html>
<form action="radio.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"  />Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
</form>
```